# How to configure Apache reverse proxy from sub-directory to alternate port using SSL

Tags: apache, proxy

I've been working for some time with a weird setup, and I believe proxying can solve some of my problems, but no matter how much I read I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the configuration. I'm hoping someone here can shed some light on if this is possible, and if so, how it would work.

To start, I have a hosted domain, `http://example.com`. On there, I have a subdomain which points to my house, and that subdomain's redirect is handled through the cPanel API on a script from my home server. That subdomain is `http://hda.example.com`.

Of note, I have a GeoTrust SSL cert for that subdomain. Any subfolder on that domain, for example, `https://hda.example.com/torquetest`. This will matter more later on.

I also have some services on alt ports. The one that comes to mind is netdata, which is on `http://hda.example.com:19999`. I want to put this behind a password AND enforce SSL over it.

I've seen a guide to do this here:
https://blog.ueffing.net/post/2016/04/03/how-to-install-firehol-netdata-on-a-linux-ubuntu-14-04-box-and-run-it-behind-an-apache2-proxy-with-basic-auth-protection/

That involves setting up a site as a virtualhost. The virtualhost is a subdomain, so it would be something like `http://netdata.hda.example.com`. I would prefer to have `http://hda.example.com/netdata` direct there. Is proxying like that to a subdirectory possible, and if so, what does the sites-available file need to look like? I tried a bunch of stuff, but when I did "apachectl configcheck" failed in a myriad of ways.

Final question... if I get that configured correctly, a rule to enforce pushing SSL should work with my existing cert, correct?